# C# (vs2022) Windows forms Datagridview pagination does not show row header numbers of page 1 on first run

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, datagridview, visual-studio-2022

I am customizing DataGridView using C# in vs2022. With pagination I want to show row numbers on row headers. Everything is working perfectly but as I run DataGriddView form, header rows on page 1 do not show numbers but when I click on page 2 or any other page, header rows display rows properly and if I click on page 1, it also shows number properly.
Only when datagridview run first page 1 does not show row headers.

I have tried all the possible solutions in past few days but problem could not be solved. Guys your help will be highly appreciated.....
**Here is a code for styling datagridview**

```
    void StyleDatagridview()
    {
        //----------GRID SETTINGS----------
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.StandardTab = true;
        dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Control;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        //dataGridView1.recor

        //----------COLUMN SETTINGS----------
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 10);
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 28;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
        //dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(37, 37, 38);
        //dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;

        //----------ROW SETTINGS----------
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 50;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = true;
        dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(238, 239, 249);
        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 28;

        //----------CELL SETTINGS----------
        dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 176, 240);
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 10);
    }
```

Here is a code for populating datagridview header rows on button click showing page number

```
    private void populateGridRowHeader(int rowNumber)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
            row.HeaderCell.Value = rowNumber.ToString();
            rowNumber++;
        }
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders);
        //dataGridView1./*UpdateCellValue*/();
    }
```

here's code for grid binding invokes from constructor

```
        private void BindGrid(int pageIndex)
    {
        //dataGridView1
        int recordCount = 0;
        string empName = txtEmployee.Text.Trim();
        DataTable dt;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(empName))
        {
             dt = DBHelper.readDataFromStoredProc("GetWSPageWise", null, pageIndex, PageSize, out recordCount);
        }
        else
        {
             dt = DBHelper.readDataFromStoredProc("GetWSPageWiseFilter", empName, pageIndex, PageSize, out recordCount);

        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        PopulatePager(recordCount, pageIndex);

    }
```

Comment: is this winform application ?

Comment: @ImamulKarimTonmoy yes its windows forms application

Comment: @burnsi code is added with question please.

Comment: where you placed your grid binding code. in constructor?

Comment: @ImamulKarimTonmoy grid binding code is uploaded

Comment: call the method BindGrid from the Form_Loading event.

Comment: Its already calling from Form_Load event

Comment: you said "here's code for grid binding invokes from constructor"